# Transform recursive function to recursive arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have the following code with a recursive function which I would like to transform to recursive arrow function:

```
const hasAccess = menuSections.some(function s(x) {
  if (x.link === route.routeConfig.path) {
    return true;
  }

  if (x.sections) {
    return (x.sections.some(s));
  }

  return false;
});
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Why? The function doesn't use `this`, `arguments` or anything else that would be handled *differently* by an arrow function. It **does** use its own name to recurse, and arrow functions are anonymous. For your problem a function expression has benefits over an arrow function but an arrow function has no benefits at all over a function expression.

Comment: @Quentin because it's a requirement from an exercise

Answer (score 1):

You could use an own function for callback and shorten the conditions for the return value.

```
const 
    check = x => x.link === route.routeConfig.path || x.sections && x.sections.some(check),
    hasAccess = menuSections.some(check);
```

Comment: It possibly should be `!!x.sections` so that, per the OP, it returns a boolean rather than *undefined*, or null, or 0 or ….

Comment: it is a callback used in `some`, so any falsy value works.